# Keep the dropdown values after submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, coldfusion

Creating dropdown box dynamically and options are adding through javascript arrays and I wanted to keep the values after i submit the form. Let us say if I select 'OOR' and '2' then after submit the form, I wanted to see these values in those dropdowns.

Thanks.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

    OORs=new Array("1","2","3","4");
    NoOORs=new Array("A","B","C");

    populateSelect();
    $(function() {


        $('#fenv').change(function(){
            populateSelect();
        });

    });
    function populateSelect(){

        fenv=$('#fenv').val();

        $('#market').html('');
        if(fenv=='OOR'){
            $.each(OORs,function(index,t) {
                $("#market").append("<option value='"+t+"'>" +t+ "</option>");
            });
        }
        else {
            $.each(NoOORs,function(index,t) {
                $("#market").append("<option value='"+t+"'>" +t+ "</option>");
            });

        }

    }
</script>

<form>
    <select id="fenv" NAME="fenv">
        <option value="OOR2">OOR2</option>
        <option value="OOR">OOR</option>

    </select>

    <select id="market" name="market"></select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  >
</form>
```

Comment: What about it isn't working? Which version of IE? What do you expect it to do? What is it actually doing?

Comment: when I select 'OOR' then market dropdown should show the values (1,2,3,4,5). but here market dropdown is NOT populating values in IE browser when I select OOR from first dropdown(fenv). But in Firefox it is showing values fine. I am using IE11 version.

Comment: I put together a jsfiddle that seems to be working in both browsers. https://jsfiddle.net/y16se3uj/

Comment: But after submitting the form, how can I keep the values which we have selected before submit.

Comment: see the updated code above. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of hidden fields to persist the data after form submits. Like this:

```
    OORs=new Array("1","2","3","4");
    NoOORs=new Array("A","B","C");

    populateSelect();
    $(function() {


        $('#fenv').change(function(){
            populateSelect();
        });

    });
    function populateSelect(){

        fenv=$('#fenv').val();
        marketvalues = [];

        $('#market').html('');
        if(fenv=='OOR'){
            $.each(OORs,function(index,t) {
                $("#market").append("<option value='"+t+"'>" +t+ "</option>");
                marketvalues.push(t);
            });
        }
        else {
            $.each(NoOORs,function(index,t) {
                $("#market").append("<option value='"+t+"'>" +t+ "</option>");
                marketvalues.push(t);
            });

        }
        $("#marketvalues").val(marketvalues.join(","));
    }
</script>

<form method="post">
    <select id="fenv" NAME="fenv">
        <option value="OOR2" <cfif structKeyExists(form, "fenv") and form.fenv EQ "OOR2"> selected="selected"</cfif>>OOR2</option>
        <option value="OOR" <cfif structKeyExists(form, "fenv") and form.fenv EQ "OOR"> selected="selected"</cfif>>OOR</option>

    </select>

    <select id="market" name="market">
    <cfif structKeyExists(form, "marketvalues") and trim(form.marketvalues) NEQ "">
        <cfloop list="#form.marketvalues#" index="mv">
            <option value="#mv#" <cfif form.market EQ mv> selected="selected"</cfif>>#mv#</option>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="marketvalues" id="marketvalues" value=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj, thanks for your help. working like champ.

Answer (score 0):

To persist some data you will need to use php session or post.

For the first select it should be easy:

```
<select id="fenv" NAME="fenv">
    <option value="OOR2" <?php if($_POST["fenv"]=="OOR2") echo "selected";?>>OOR2</option>
    <option value="OOR" <?php if($_POST["fenv"]=="OOR") echo "selected";?>>OOR</option>
</select>
```

For the second part is more complicated tho. You could do some javascript magic setting it to the propper value:

```
var element = document.getElementById('market');
element.value = "<?php echo(isset($_POST['market'])&&($_POST['market']!='')?$_POST['market']:'');?>";
```

Comment: Hi LordNeo, thanks for your response. But we are using coldfusion not php. can you please let me know how we can implement in coldfusion ?

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to do.

Once you submit your form (to the same page only), you can check for the submit condition in CF and run a JavaScript function that takes the submitted values.

1. Submit the form
2. fn populateSelect() populates the select boxes
3. CFIF checks if the page load is a form submission
4. runs the fn afterFormSubmitSetSelectedValues(fenv, market) values

   ```
   <form method="post">
       <select id="fenv" NAME="fenv">
           <option value="OOR2">OOR2</option>
           <option value="OOR">OOR</option>
       </select>
       <select id="market" name="market"></select>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
   </form>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script language="javascript">
       var OORs = ["1","2","3","4"], //declaring the OORs
           NoOORs = ["A","B","C"], //the NoOORs
           fenvRef = $('#fenv'),  //creating the ref using jQuery Once, so we do not need to do a DOM query again and again
           marketRef = $('#market'), // same for market
           populateSelect = function () {

               var fenv = fenvRef.val(), 
                   marketvalues = [];

               marketRef.html('');

               if ('OOR' === fenv) {
                   $.each(OORs, function(index,t) {
                       marketRef.append("<option value='" + t + "'>" + t + "</option>");
                       marketvalues.push(t);
                   });
               } else {
                   $.each(NoOORs, function(index,t) {
                       marketRef.append("<option value='" + t + "'>" + t + "</option>");
                       marketvalues.push(t);
                   });
               }
           },
           afterFormSubmitSetSelectedValues = function (fenv, market) { // upon reload this Fn() will set the selected values
               fenvRef.val(fenv);
               if ('OOR' === fenv) {
                   populateSelect();
               }
               marketRef.val(market);
           };

           $(function() {
               fenvRef.change(function() {
                   populateSelect();
               });
           });

           // this will populate the initial values
           populateSelect();

           <cfif isDefined('form') AND structKeyExists(form, 'submit')>
           //only executed if the form is previously submitted
               afterFormSubmitSetSelectedValues('<cfoutput>#form.fenv#</cfoutput>', '<cfoutput>#form.market#</cfoutput>');
           </cfif>
   </script>
   ```

Good luck!